# how to install and start the ear automatically using maven for web sphere6

Tags: maven-2, websphere-6.1

I am using maven build for Automation. Can any one suggest me, how to install ear and start the ear at server side using maven  For WebSphere 6.1

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

There aren't ready turn-key solutions available for this. However you can accomplish your goal with wsadmin [deployment](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/txml_callappinstall.html) [scripting](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html). Run the required commands from [custom plugin](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html) you develop or [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).